# Find all ocurrences of substrings with [tokens] in string and place them in int array

Tags: c#

I have a working code for replacing a single substring within [] in a string. This worked for a "[1]" in a string:

```
private string returnWithLinks(string adminString, int adminId)
    {
        var returnString = "Nothing at all";

        int pFrom = adminString.IndexOf("[") + "[".Length;
        int pTo = adminString.LastIndexOf("]");

        var getSourceId = adminString.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

        int i = 0;
        bool tryParse = int.TryParse(getSourceId, out i);
        if(!tryParse) {returnString = "this is not an int!";} else {
            if(i == 1) {
                returnString = adminString.Replace("[1]", "<a>something</a>" + var1fromsomwhere + i);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                returnString = adminString.Replace("[2]", "<a>other something</a>" + var2fromsomwhere + i);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                returnString = adminString.Replace("[3]", "<a>other something</a>" + var3fromsomwhere + i);
            } else if (i == 4) {
                returnString = adminString.Replace("[4]", "<a>other something</a>" + var4fromsomwhere + i);
            } else if (i == 5) {
                returnString = adminString.Replace("[5]", "<a>other something</a>" + var5fromsomwhere + i);
            }
        }
        return returnString;
    }
```

However I now need to be able to replace all occurences of the tokens such as:

```
adminString = "[1][2]somthingelse[2]another[4]aa";
```

I was think about placing all the ints inside token on an int array, then looping each int with the if clauses, but creating the array is completly out of my leage.

How can I achieve this?

After having the array I will loop through it with the if clauses.

Comment: what happens if the int is not found like [12336588] ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not found"?  There is an int between the tokens in that example.

Comment: yeah but your code only accounts for ints between 1 and 5.... so what happens if the int is 6 or 32586255.......... what then?

Comment: In the code above it would return "Nothing at all". But i guess a better option would be not to replace the token.

Comment: you do not need an array

Comment: single line of code will do it.  look at my answer.  no need for if statements either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an array or even a loop.

There are many ways to do this... For example using a dictionary.

But in your case there is no need to complicate things.

A single line of code will replace everything like this:

```
    private string returnWithLinks(string adminString, int adminId)
    {
            var returnString = adminString
               .Replace("[1]", "<a>something</a>" + var1fromsomwhere + 1)
               .Replace("[2]", "<a>something</a>" + var2fromsomwhere + 2)
               .Replace("[3]", "<a>something</a>" + var3fromsomwhere + 3)
               .Replace("[4]", "<a>something</a>" + var4fromsomwhere + 4)
               .Replace("[5]", "<a>something</a>" + var5fromsomwhere + 5);

            return returnString;
    }
```

Doing with a dictionary and a loop:

```
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _replacements = new 
    Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "[1]", "<a>something</a>" + var1fromsomwhere + 1 },
        { "[2]", "<a>something</a>" + var2fromsomwhere + 2 },
        { "[3]", "<a>something</a>" + var3fromsomwhere + 3 },
        { "[4]", "<a>something</a>" + var4fromsomwhere + 4 },
        { "[5]", "<a>something</a>" + var5fromsomwhere + 5 },            
    };
    private string returnWithLinks(string adminString, int adminId)
    {
            var keys = _replacements.Keys.ToArray();
            var returnString = adminString;

            for(var i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                var key = keys[0];

                returnString = returnString.Replace(key, _replacements[key]);
            }

            return returnString;
    }
```

As you can see dictionary seems cleaner but in terms of maintenance and number of lines of code is the exact same thing.

You will still need to add a line to the dictionary for every replacement.

The only reason i would do it in a loop with a dictionary would be if the dictionary is NOT hardcoded.

Meaning if the dictionary was filled with values from a database for example.

Another downside of the loop is the amount of string allocations one extra allocation per iteration.

Comment: You shame me with such a simple solution :)

Comment: A dict would not help here since I need to check if a variable is not null before I replace it. For example [1] is replaced by var1fromsomwhere only if it's not null. But I can use the .Replace one at a time after an if clause. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

You can just run replace in a loop.

```
var tokens = new[] { "[1]", "[2]", "[3]", "[4]" };
var replacements = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

var adminString = "[1][2]somthingelse[2]another[4]aa";
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
   adminString = adminString.Replace(tokens[i], replacements[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(adminString); //onetwosomthingelsetwoanotherfouraa
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception if the value is not within the range of the loop and will not work for values that are not sequential like  2,7,9,5698,36,158

Comment: Of course that this code is not ready for production. As you suggested in your answer for example dictionary may be used. Loop is here just to not repeat lines with replace for every token.